# ASP.NET Core Error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream'

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I created a server based on ASP.NET Core 3 preview 6 and try to run it in the docker based on linux. Any request I get an error: "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'."

When running Kestrel on a local machine (windows server 2012), everything works fine for me. I do not use any libraries except AspNetCore and NewtonsoftJson. The project was created using the Controller API template.

Project.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <UserSecretsId>2bd64d79-ff97-4e47-8cbd-514aa4874416</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.7.12" />
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTest"
RUN dotnet build "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DockerTest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Error:

```
Connection id "0HLOBGRFHMARF", Request id "0HLOBGRFHMARF:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.NewtonsoftJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.NewtonsoftJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I tried to launch a docker based on dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0.0-preview6, but I didn’t notice any changes.

Also, as I understand it, some libraries have been removed from asp.net Core 3, including Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.

I even added  to the project, but again did not notice the difference

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I try to make a test with your dockerfile and .csproj. It will fail to build.

Comment: @TaoZhou https://hub.docker.com/r/lifefreedom11/life/builds see  
a19b694 (use buster) and 8ecc8a5 (use stretch-slim) commit source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a working demo, try to change your dockerfile to replace `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim` with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim` and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-stretch` with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
```

Comment: The image based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim did not start on my hosting, citing an unsupported image. On this occasion, I have already written in support of hosting.

Comment: I was able to run docker based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-alpine. I do not understand much of a difference between them, maybe you know?

Comment: @LIFEfreedom Are you sure you running under linux docker container?

Comment: @LIFEfreedom You could check this [ASP.NET Core Runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/)

Comment: The problem with the FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim is related to the supported distributions for Docker containers (docs.jelastic.com/docker-supported-distributions). Jelastic does not support Debian 10